# Arduino method returns only 0

Tags: arduino

I have written a simple method, which should generate a 5 digit passcode, only with the digits: 1, 2, 3, 4 (for example: 42132)
In order to do that, I am using an ESP32 with 4 PushButtons. Each button represents a digit.

But when I test my method, it just returns '00000'. The problem: The method is not waiting for me to push a button, it instantly returns 0. And I have changed the method x times by now, and I just can't figure out why it's returning only 00000 without waiting for me to push buttons.

I have already tried to use a for-loop in the method, but the result was the same. It returned '00000', as the method was not waiting for me to push buttons.

My Code:

```cpp
String pcode="";
int buttonid;

void loop() {

  for(int j=0; j< 5;) {

    pcode = pcode + passcode();
    j++;
  }

  if(pcode.length() == 5){

  Serial.println(pcode);

  }

}

static int passcode(){  

    buttonStateRED=digitalRead(redButton);

    buttonStateBLUE=digitalRead(blueButton);

    buttonStateYELLOW=digitalRead(yellowButton);

    buttonStateGREEN=digitalRead(greenButton);

    if(buttonStateRED == HIGH)
    {
      buttonid=1;
    }
    else if(buttonStateBLUE == HIGH)
    {
      buttonid=2;
    }
    else if(buttonStateYELLOW == HIGH)
    {
      buttonid=3;
    }
    else if(buttonStateGREEN == HIGH)
    {
      buttonid=4;
    }
  return buttonid;
}
```

What I need, is that the method waits for me to push 5 buttons (f.e. Button 3, Button 2, Button 3, Button 1, Button 4 --> Passcode = 32314).

Answer (score 0):

Try this modification,

```
int passcode(){

   buttonStateRED = LOW;
   buttonStateBLUE = LOW;
   buttonStateYELLOW = LOW;
   buttonStateGREEN = LOW;

   do {

           buttonStateRED=digitalRead(redButton);
           buttonStateBLUE=digitalRead(blueButton);
           buttonStateYELLOW=digitalRead(yellowButton);
           buttonStateGREEN=digitalRead(greenButton);

       }while(buttonStateRED != HIGH && buttonStateBLUE != HIGH && buttonStateYELLOW != HIGH && buttonStateGREEN != HIGH);

    if(buttonStateRED == HIGH)
    {
      buttonid=1;
    }
    else if(buttonStateBLUE == HIGH)
    {
      buttonid=2;
    }
    else if(buttonStateYELLOW == HIGH)
    {
      buttonid=3;
    }
    else if(buttonStateGREEN == HIGH)
    {
      buttonid=4;
    }

    return buttonid;
}
```

Pull down all the buttons and also add a delay component inside the for loop which calls the passcode method.

Comment: Without a delay, it just does for example "33333" when I press 1x 3. With delay the user has to time the input perfectly :/ So I don't think that that's a perfect solution

Answer (score 0):

You need an interrupt function! now what is a interrupt function you may ask? Is exactly what you need, this function only triggers if some statement is fulfilled!

How to use it? set the "insertwhilepressed" function in your code, put the interrupt function on your loop function, the program will run in circles UNTIL anyone presses anything.

Why you should do that? well, in your code you are simply running a For inside of a loop, which means there is no trigger to tell your code when it should start getting the information it needs to get. Another solution would be putting an IF before the for, but you would have to hand with the time problem called ripple effect, so the best solution for you is definitely an interrupt function.

So whats the function? [This one right here](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/external-interrupts/attachinterrupt/)

Wanna learn more about interruptions? [There is a video that might help you](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=201&v=QtyOiTw0oQc)

Comment: Also, remember to use the FALL mode, since you are using push buttons and I assume they are well grounded, FALL mode in the interruption will only run after you PRESS AND RELEASE the button!

Comment: sorry but I don't quit understand:/ in my setup I've written: attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(redButton), passcode, FALLING);
    attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(blueButton), passcode, FALLING);
    attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(yellowButton), passcode, FALLING);
    attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(greenButton), passcode, FALLING);, now it throws me an error: invalid conversion from 'int (*)()' to 'void (*)()' [-fpermissive]

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple problems with your code:

1. You never wrote any code that would wait for a button press.
2. If the button wasn't pressed `passcode()` just returns the last button pressed.
3. A single button press will register as multiple button presses.
4. You are also indefinitely concatenating to `pcode`, which makes it run out of memory and crash.

To fix it you need to:

1. Make `passcode()` return some value when a button wasn't pressed.
2. Ignore the invalid button press or if it's the same as the last one (don't add it to `pcode`).
3. When you get the 5 characters for the code and don't need it anymore, empty the `pcode` string.

```cpp
String pcode = "";
int last_key = -1;

void loop() {
    int key = passcode();
    if (key != -1 && last_key != key) // if the button  was actually pressed
        pcode = pcode + key; // add key to code
    }
    last_key = key;

    if(pcode.length() == 5){
        Serial.println(pcode);
        pcode = ""; // reset the string
    }
}

static int passcode() {
    if (digitalRead(redButton) == HIGH)
        return 1;
    if (digitalRead(blueButton) == HIGH)
        return 2;
    if (digitalRead(yellowButton) == HIGH)
        return 3;
    if (digitalRead(greenButton) == HIGH)
        return 4;
    return -1; // no button was pressed
}
```

The code probably also needs some [debouncing](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Debounce).